# Does anyone know or have a introductory Planescape adventure?

Tags: dnd-4e, game-recommendation, one-shot, planescape

I'm looking for an introductory adventure for the Planescape setting that I could use to sell people on Planescape.

Ideally, I'm looking for an adventure that would satisfy the following criteria:

1. A one-shot that we could run with pre-generated characters
2. For a party of 4-5 characters
3. Fit for some players that are new to RPGs in general
4. Fit for introducing players that are new with Planescape to the background
5. Able to be fit into one or two sessions, to 8 hours of total gameplay, tops.
6. It should ideally contain as little combat as possible, maybe just an encounter or two to get the mechanics of it, and how the setting affects it.

Within those constraints, the high points of the scenario should be those of Planescape: interesting NPCs, creative ways to solve the problems, debating over the philosophical fine points of the setting.

I'm looking for something that shouldn't be too heavy on the new players, but also give them a nice overview while presenting them with some nice brain-teasers. It doesn't matter to me if the adventure is 4e or not, I'm happy to convert from another version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can get access to the campaign setting starter package, particularly the book [*Sigil and Beyond*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/17267/Planescape-Campaign-Setting-2e?it=1), you will find two very excellent starter modules which are combat-light and introduce the settting. Each one is designed for 4-5 inexperienced players and can be completed in one or two sessions.

**For the Price of a Rose**

*The PCs are hired to solve the mystery of midnight prowlers in the garden of Lady Kindernis's castle. Someone is clipping the heads off of her prized roses and discarding heads from completely different roses in their place. Why would this be?*

**Misplaced Spirit**

*A petitioner from the Celestial Bureaucracy has escaped her afterlife plane and is roaming Sigil. The PCs are hired to return her, whether she likes it or not. But is that truly the right thing to do?*

---

Additionally, if you want to continue beyond these short modules, I strongly recommend [Doors to the Unknown](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078690447X). This module is recommended by myself and the (hopefully soon-to-be-back-online) [Planewalker community site](http://www.planewalker.com/). It's a coherent module with lots of interesting subtext to the story which could still manage to hold its own on nothing but the skeleton of its plot. It has all of the information you need about the factions and planes for the module contained within the book itself.

*When four doors appear in the Cage, the barmies crawl out of the shadows, and the heroes get drawn into events that could have consequences for the entire multiverse. Each door leads to a different plane and a different deadly challenge for the player characters. Together they offer a way to stop an ancient menace before it strikes again.*

It is designed for a party of 4-6 players of low-to-mid levels and has a good variety of activity and scenes.

Please note that all of the modules I have listed here are AD&D, but the stories are easy enough to convert, which you mentioned is okay. Most official Planescape material is AD&D.

Comment: +1 for Sigil and Beyond; From memory, *For the Price of a Rose* works as an introduction for clueless primes, and *Misplaced Spirit* works as an introduction for new planars, so it covers two possible party compositions.

Comment: Your memory is correct. I have run both and they both serve as a great intro. I'd recommend doing a clueless prime party (via *Price of a Rose*) for a group of players who literally know nothing about Planescape. If they've been told a bit, played PS:T, or something similar, I'd start with *Misplaced Spirit*.